# VB6 Recursion and return variables in functions

Tags: recursion, syntax, vb6

This is a syntax question. I am confused as to when the "return variable" in a Function is used as a return variable or as a method call. For instance, if I have:

```
Function foo() As Boolean
     foo = True
     foo = foo And bar
End Function
```

Does the second line in this function act as a recursive call to foo, or does it resolve to true from the previous assignment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the value as of the last assignment:

```
foo = foo And bar
```

To make a recursive call:

```
foo = foo() And bar
```

The `()` makes all the difference. (BTW, this applies to VBA too.)